# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

I am using below code in my project. After update to swift 4 and run my app crashed . How can I fix it?

Code:

```
 func from(systemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem)-> UIImage? {
    let tempItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: systemItem, target: nil, action: nil)

    // add to toolbar and render it
    UIToolbar().setItems([tempItem], animated: false)

    // got image from real uibutton
    let itemView = tempItem.value(forKey: "view") as! UIView
    for view in itemView.subviews {
        if let button = view as? UIButton, let imageView = button.imageView {
            return imageView.image
        }
    }

    return nil

    }
 }
    extension UITextView {

static let ScrollModeBottom = "UITextFieldScrollModeBottom"
static let ScrollModeUp = "UITextFieldScrollModeUp"
static let ScrollModeMiddle = "UITextFieldScrollModeMiddle"

func scrollToBotom() {
    let range = NSMakeRange((text as NSString).length - 1, 1);
    scrollRangeToVisible(range);
}

var scrollMode: String {
    let scrollViewHeight: Float = Float(frame.size.height)
    let scrollContentSizeHeight: Float = Float(contentSize.height)
    let scrollOffset: Float = Float(contentOffset.y)

    if scrollOffset == 0 {
        return UITextView.ScrollModeUp
    } else if scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight == scrollContentSizeHeight {
        return UITextView.ScrollModeBottom
    } else {
        return UITextView.ScrollModeMiddle
    }
}
```

}

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: Where does the error occur and what is the exception reason? I guess the error occurs in the line to get the `view` via KVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 // add to toolbar and render it
    let bar = UIToolbar()
    bar.setItems([tempItem],
                 animated: false)
    bar.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)

    //got image from real uibutton
    let itemView = tempItem.value(forKey: "view") as! UIView
    for view in itemView.subviews {
        if let button = view as? UIButton,
            let image = button.imageView?.image {
            return image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        }
    }

    return nil
  }
}
```